# How to set 'update_weights' in OpenCV's MLP implementation?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn

I'm used to using `sklearn`, whose documentation I find very easy to follow. However, I now need to learn to use `OpenCV` - in particular, I need to be able to use an MLP classifier, and to update its weights as new training data comes in.

In sklearn, this can be done using the `partial_fit` method. According to the OpenCV documentation, there is an `UPDATE_WEIGHTS` flag that can be set, but I can't figure out how to include it in my code.

Here's a MCVE of what I have so far:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import numpy as np
import cv2
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

def softmax(x):
    softmaxes = np.zeros(x.shape)
    for i in range(x.shape[1]):
        softmaxes[:, i] = np.exp(x)[:, i]/np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=1)
    return softmaxes

data = load_breast_cancer()
X = data.data
y = data.target.reshape(-1, 1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1729)

y2 = np.zeros((y_train.shape[0], 2))
y2[:,0] = np.where(y_train==0, 1, 0)
y2[:,1] = np.where(y_train==1, 1, 0)

ann = cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_create()
ann.setLayerSizes(np.array([X.shape[1], y2.shape[1]]))
ann.setActivationFunction(cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_SIGMOID_SYM)
ann.train(np.float32(X_train), cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, np.float32(y2))

mlp = MLPClassifier()
mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)

preds_proba = softmax(ann.predict(np.float32(X_test))[1])
print(roc_auc_score(y_test, preds_proba[:,1]))
print(roc_auc_score(y_test, mlp.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]))
```

As the score between the OpenCV classifier and the sklearn learn one are comparable, I'm pretty confident it's implemented correctly.

How can I modify this code, so that when a new training sample comes in, I can update the weights based on that sample alone, rather than retraining on the entire train set?

The equivalent in `sklearn` would be:
`mlp.partial_fit(X_new_sample, y_new_sample)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer. The syntax is the following:

```
ann.train(cv2.ml.TrainData_create(np.float32(X), 0, np.float32(y)), flags=1)
```